# Why can't Macbook users upload MOV files to HTML file input forms?

Tags: html, forms, macos, video, file-upload

I am seeing a very strange behavior on a website I am developing where Macbook users are unable to upload MOV files from their computers to the following HTML `input` element:

```html
<input type="file" name="video_file" accept=".webm,.mp4,.mov" capture="environment" required="">
```

When they click in `input` element, their file browser opens, and the MOV files appear greyed-out and disabled, thus they are unable to upload them to the web form. This relatively recent [Google Photos support thread](https://support.google.com/photos/thread/115529?hl=en) confirms that I am not crazy.

Unfortunately, I am not able to directly debug or diagnose this problem, as I do not have a Macbook handy.

Comment: just remove [capture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#capture) form accept, and add it as attribute.

Comment: I'm confused; Why is this tagged "iOS"?

Comment: @NicolasMiari my mistake. I changed iOS to MacOS

Comment: @ROOT I don't think your suggestion will affect Macbooks, because they don't have an `environment`-facing camera. I edited my question because the `capture` data is probably a red herring. I'm happy to be proven wrong by anyone that can test this with a Macbook.

Comment: @ChrisConlan, I'm using Mac, I did my test on Chrome, Safari it worked fine when I added the change I suggested.

Comment: @ROOT Thanks. I'll test this with my client and verify.